# WP7 ScrollViewer Snap-Back and Auto scrollbar visibility issues on windows phone

Tags: c#, silverlight, xaml, windows-phone-7, windows-phone

I have an application that displays wrapped text in a ScrollViewer that takes up a fixed height of the page. I set the HorizontalScrollBarVisibility to Disabled, and the VerticalScrollBarVisibility to Auto.

The usability problems I'm having are as follows:
Despite being set to Auto, if the content is smaller than the ScrollViewer, then the content can still scroll up and down, either scrolling past the end or hiding a portion of the text. I would like the ScrollViewer not to allow scrolling when the entire content fits inside its bounds. At the very least it should always snap the content back into view when you over-scroll.

Secondly, when the content does scroll, it sometimes gets stuck past the end and won't "snap back" from the over-scroll. For example, if the content fits fully in the ScrollViewer, and you drag your finger up or down on the text, the text will be obscured by the top or bottom of the ScrollViewer, and won't snap back. If however you drag your finger up starting from outside of the content of the ScrollViewer, it will snap back when you scroll past either end. I would like the "snap back" behavior to happen whether you drag on the content or outside of the content. Is that possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First issue: If your content isn't large enough to warrant the need for a scroll viewer don't put it in one. If the size of the content changes only enable the scrollbar when the volume of content warrants it.

Can you provide a way of reproducing the second issue.

Comment: I am now using a form of your second suggestion - namely setting the VerticalScrollBarVisibility to Disabled when the content is too small to need scrolling. However, the second issue remains. It doesn't "stick" for simple controls, like a TextBlock with TextWrapping turned on, but it does stick when the content is a WrapPanel from the Silverlight Toolkit for WP7. I made sure the WrapPanel's VerticalAlignment is set to "Top" and not Stretch, so I know it isn't considering the empty space as "content".

Comment: Aha! It looks like some of the controls in the content of the scrollviewer were subscribing to ManipulatingCompleted RoutedEvents and setting e.Handled = true, which meant the ScrollViewer didn't get them.